# Text not showing as bold in slides

Tags: beamer, bold, preamble

I am preparing some slides and want to use bold text occasionally in a definition. I *can* use bold text outside a definition, but it just wont work inside. I was sent a template for the slides and I suspect it is something in the preamble but not sure what, so here is what I have at the top of the document (which I did not set up myself):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts, tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary[topaths]

\newcommand\importantstuff[3]{
    \node[black!30!white] at (#1+0.1,#2-0.1) {
        \scalebox{2}{\Huge\texttt{#3}} 
    };
    \node at (#1,#2) {
        \scalebox{2}{\Huge\texttt{#3}} 
    };
}


\usetheme{Berkeley}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\let\Tiny=\tiny
\DeclareMathOperator{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{\mathrm{Aut}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Sym}{\mathrm{Sym}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cS}{\mathcal{S}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\expec}{\mathbb{E}}
\newtheorem{cconj}{Conjecture (Cherlin)}
\newtheorem{thrm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{princ}{Principle}
\newtheorem{corl}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{met}{Method}
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{lema}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{deft}{Definition}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}
\title{Title}
\author{Name}
\date{Date}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}


\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Overview}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Definitions}

\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Subtuples}
\uncover<1->{\begin{deft}[Subtuple] Let $n \in \mathbb{N} $ and let $ I \in \Omega ^{n} $, where $ I = ( I_{1}  , \dots , I_{n} ) $. Suppose $1 \leq m \leq n $. An \textbf{$m$-subtuple} of $I$ is an $m$-tuple $( I_{p_{1} } , \dots , I_{ p_{m} } ) $ where $1 \leq p_{1}  <  \dots < p_{m} \leq n $.
\end{deft}}
\uncover<2->{As above, whenever $I, J \in \Omega^{n} $, assume the entries are written as $ I = ( I _{1} , \dots , I_{n} ) $ and $ I = ( J _{1} , \dots , J_{n} ) $.}
\uncover<3->{
\medskip
\begin{exmp}
Let $ (5, 2, 3, 1) \in \mathbb{Z} ^{4} $. A $3$-subtuple of this is $(5,3,1) $ and another is $(2,3,1) $. An example of a $2$-subtuple is $(2,3) $.
\end{exmp}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The non-bold text does show in italics for me but the text inside \textbf shows as plain, non-italic, non-bold text. This is how it looks for me;

[image: Definition]

Edit: included complete example as in my slides & added screen shot.

Comment: Completed example added

Comment: Would rather not pasted the full slides, but I have made a test document that still has the same issue. I have updated the above post with the exact code.

Comment: Thank you; however, I still cannot reproduce the issue. I obtain bold text both with TeXLive2017 and 2020. Does the log file complain about missing fonts?

Comment: Yes it does actually. One warning says "Font shape 'OT1/cmss/bx/it' undefined(Font) using  'OT1/cmss/b/it' instead"

Another warning says "Some front shapes were not available, defaults substituted."

Comment: Uhm, the warning is normal and I expected it but this still does not explain the result. You should get upright bold, not upright normal. Does adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` or `\usepackage{lmodern}` help?

Comment: Yes, both of those work perfectly, thanks! Please could you post your comment as a normal post then I can flag it as answered for you?

Comment: The point is that that's not really an answer. Under normal circumstances TeX is trying to use OT1 CM bold italic, which does not exist, and recovers by switching to bold upright. The two "solutions" I proposed just use another font which has the required combination. However, I still have no idea why you get an upright normal font...